# Manejo de 2 o más sesiones dentro del mismo dominio

Tags: php, session

nunca he llegado a tener 2 sesiones diferentes dentro de un mismo dominio, y necesito ayuda para saber como manejarlas ambas.

Ambas páginas están dentro del mismo dominio, pero en lugares totalmente diferentes.
Primero tuve el problema de que las sesiones se abrían ambas al usar cualquier login, por lo que cambié el nombre de las variables al iniciar la sesión.

Esta es una sección del login.php, en donde le asigno diferentes nombres a las variables.

```
//Si el usuario existe blah blah blah
if (password_verify($password, $hashed_password)) {
    session_start();
    $_SESSION["logginA"] = true;
    $_SESSION["idA"] = $id;
    $_SESSION["userA"] = $username;
    header("location: dashboard.php");
} else {
    $password_err = "La contraseña que has ingresado no es válida.";
}
```

Y cuando cierro sesión, ahora mismo, ambas apuntan al mismo logout, el cual cierra todas las sesiones

```
<?php
session_start();
$_SESSION = array();
session_destroy();
header("location: login.php");
exit;
?>
```

¿Que cambios o arreglos debo realizar para manejar correctamente ambas sesiones?

Comment: Tienes 2 opciones, la primera haz la session array y en $_SESSION["userA"] metes varias, la otra es simplemente crear diferentes variables $_SESSION["userA1"],$_SESSION["userA2"],...

Comment: Puedes crear dos sesiones distintas mediante `session_id()`, revisa [esta respuesta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24965106/5587982). Lo que conviene evaluar aquí es si necesitas realmente dos sesiones o una misma sesión con diferentes áreas. Como bien dice @JosueVargas, eso también es posible. ¿Por qué crees que necesitas dos sesiones?

Comment: No creo, las necesito. Una sección es para uso de X grupo de personas, el otro es para Y grupo de personas. Sesiones diferentes e inicios diferentes. Unos tienen usuarios, otros son con ids.

Comment: Pues puedes tener sesiones distintas como se indica en la respuesta. Tienes que darle un ID, luego abrirla, luego cerrar con `session_write_close()` y luego hacer el mismo procedimiento con la otra sesión.

Comment: Gracias @A.Cedano haré las pruebas y luego aplicaré los cambios ;)

Comment: Si la **seguridad** es importante en tu contexto, revisa por favor lo dicho en [esta respuesta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49844847/5587982).